# Using Monte Carlo standard error to determine the ideal number of trials?

Tags: probability, sample-size, monte-carlo

I am doing a simulation study that involves estimating the parameter $\theta$ under a specific experimental design. $\theta$ is the parameter that take on the value 1 if algorithm A is better than algorithm B, and 0 otherwise. I am repeating my simulation study for $N$ times so that I can count the number of times where the algorithm A performed better than the algorithm B. If the number of times that algorithm A performed better than algorithm B is greater than $\frac{N}{2}$, then I can conclude that $\theta$ is likely to be equal to 1.

But I am not sure how to pick the "right" value for $N$, and someone advise me that I can analyze the Monte Carlo standard error of the probability to determine the value for $N$. However, I am not very familiar with doing this kind of thing, and I am seeking a guidance on this.

The only idea that I can come up with is that if we let $\hat{\theta}$ to be an indicator variable that is equal to 1 if the event occurs, then $\sqrt{\frac{1}{N(N-1)}\sum^{N}_{i=1}(\hat{\theta}_i-\bar{\theta})^2}$ can be used as the Monte Carlo SE of estimate of bias for $\theta$, where $\bar{\theta}$ is the sample average of $\hat{\theta}$'s. However, I am not exactly sure how to use this information to determine the optimal value for $N$. Should I just try varying the value of $N$ and collect $\theta_1 \cdots \theta_N$ from each value of $N$, calculate the Monte Carlo SE for each case, and see if which value of $N$ would minimize Monte Carlo SE?

How can I determine the ideal value of $N$ by doing Monte Carlo? Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely related to your thoughts on how to proceed.

My take is that you run the Monte Carlo simulation based on an underlying size of m a total n times. Compute the variance of the estimator of interest based on m and n.

Then, apply a [sequential Stein sample size](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177706460) estimator to suggest the total of more runs required, say k.

Of interest is efficiency, so record the total number of suggested calculations, which from the above is m x (n + k).

Now, repeat the above replacing m with a different amount, say m'.  Record the new suggested value m' x (n' + k').

Are we moving in the direction of suggested fewer total calculations to achieve the same level of efficiency? If yes, repeat the process to try to further improve results by modifying the new m'.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Does the Stein sample size theorem also apply if the parameter that I am trying to estimate through the monte carlo simulation can only take on the values 0 or 1? what I am trying to do is I am simulating $N$ bernoulli trials and count the number of success from the $N$ trials. If the number of successful bernoulli trials is greater than $N/2$, then I would conclude the parameter $\theta$ to be equal to 1.